# Can an Object have multiple Compare methods for ordering based on different values?

Tags: java, comparison

Say I have a Song object like

```
public Song(){
  String artist, title;
  StringBuilder lyrics;
  int rank;
}
```

Is it possible to have multiple compare methods that, depending on the collection used, sort by a particular field?  This object already has a compare method for ordering based on the artist and title values, and I would like to be able to order based on the rank.

My current project requires us to run a search on the lyrics of the Song and return a high to low match list.  I want to use a PriorityQueue to hold the matches based on rank value.

Normally I would simply create another object to hold the Song and the rank, but this project not only plugs into a GUI interface provided by the professor, which requires any results be passed in an Song[] array, but prints out the first ten values as Rank, Artist, Title.

I can use toArray() to convert the queue, but if I use it to store anything other than Song objects, it will throw an ArrayStoreException.

So is this possible, or do I have to modify the existing compare method to sort by integer value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most ordered collections have a constructor that takes a `Comparator` as an argument.  Define a few static comparators in your `Song` class and then define things as follows:

```
Set<Song> allSongs = new TreeSet<Song>(Song.BY_TITLE);
PriorityQueue<Song> rankedSongs = new PriorityQueue<Song>(10, Song.BY_RANK);
```

There are utility classes (e.g., Guava [Ordering](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html)) that can help you build up other comparators from the basics.

Answer (score 12):

Use a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

```
Comparator<Song> rankOrder =  new Comparator<Song>() {
        public int compare(Song s1, Song e2) {
            return s1.rank - s2.rank;
        }
    };
Collections.sort(songs, rankOrder);
```

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. This is easy and helpful.

Answer (score 5):

The `compareTo` method of the `Comparable` interface typically offers the default comparison, if you want to provide another you should write a [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) object.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the constructor [`PriorityQueue(int, Comparator<? super E>)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(int,%20java.util.Comparator)) to use a different ordering.

Is there a reason for using a `PriorityQueue` apart from sorting?
`PriorityQueue` is not only inefficient if you do not need to have it sorted after each new element but can also not be used to sort in different ways. You would need a different `PriorityQueue` for each desired sorting.

Using a `List` could be sufficient and would allow you to sort using a different `Comparator` whenever you like: [`Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T>)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))

Comment: Inserting an item into a PriorityQueue is done in O(log N) time.  Java uses a modified merge sort, which has an O(N log N) runtime.  Even if I ordered an Arraylist on insertion, add time would be O(N). I'll take log time for anything when I can get it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of implementing Comparable in Song, pass a custom Comparator to your Collection of choice.

See [Object Ordering](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) for further details.